# How to sum array contents with their powers of 3

Tags: java, arrays, integer, sum, pow

I need to do something like this - user types in a number (e.g. 5) and the program shows the result of the following action: 1*1*1 + 2*2*2 + 3*3*3 + 4*4*4 + 5*5*5.
My code is following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your number:");
    int n = input.nextInt();

    int a[] = new int[n];
    int power = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= a.length; i++)
    {
        power = (int) pow(i, 3);

        // Maybe here'a the problem, a[n] has not enough space for the power (???)
        sum += a[power];
    }
    System.out.println(Result: " + sum);
}
```

I think that I understand why this code doesn't work but I will appreciate any ideas about how to do it properly and runnable.

Comment: what is the error message ?

Comment: general programming note: you make an array of length `n`, then iterate over it; instead of doing so until `array.length`, you already know `array.length` is `n`, so use `...; i<=n; ...` instead. Also, 1^anything is still 1, so start with a value 1, and add values based on 2 and up.

Comment: Is there a requirement that you utilize the array; if seems pretty pointless in the example?

Comment: There is no such requirement and it's way easier without it, thanks for help :)

Answer (score 4):

`sum += power;`, no need for `a`.

Answer (score 4):

Or simply use math :

[image]

```
int n = input.nextInt();
int result = (int)(0.25 * Math.pow(n, 2)*Math.pow(1+n,2));
```

Or even more simple, as @ajb said :

```
int result = n*n*(n+1)*(n+1)/4;
```

Comment: upvote for most obvious answer, although unlikely accepted since this is a guaranteed homework assignment =P

Comment: I'd write it `int result = n*n*(n+1)*(n+1)/4;`.

Comment: @ajb Yes even more simple =)

Comment: I would pull out `n * (n + 1) / 2` into one method that computes triangular numbers, since it might be useful separately, and then call it and square the result. The sums of cubes are the squares of the triangular numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
sum += a[power];
```

to

```
a[i-1] = power;
sum += a[i-1];
```

or forget the array altogether

```
sum += power;
```

Comment: But `a[i - 1]` hasn't been initialized. It will contain zero.

Answer (score 1):

`sum += a[power];` doesn't exist.

You need to :

1. store the `power` value in the `i`th array item.
2. add the `i`th array value to the `sum`

Change your loop body to:

```
power = (int) pow(i, 3);
a[i - 1] = power;
sum += a[i - 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing way too much work.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your number:");
int n = input.nextInt(),
    sum = 1;
for (int i=2; i<=n; i++) {
  sum += (int) Math.pow(i,3);
}
```

done. `sum` now contains the sum 1³ + 2³ + 3³ + ...

Or, more efficiently with exactly the same functionality:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your number:");
int n = input.nextInt(),
    sum = 1;
while(n > 1) {
  sum += (int) Math.pow(n--,3);
}
```

Why? Because 1 + 5³ + 4³ + 3³ + 2³ is the same as 1³ + 2³ + 3³ + 4³ + 5³

Of course you could also just directly compute that value, using actual maths, cutting all the entire algorithm with a simple arithmetic oneliner.

Comment: I don't think your last version is any more efficient.

Comment: You don't have to, but that doesn't change the fact that it is: the second example only uses two variables, rather than three.

Comment: True. I thought you meant performance, and the use of one extra local variable is unlikely to make a difference there.

Comment: Thank you, this one works great and it's not so heavy as mine.